How to get DATEDIFF between rows based on matching values in separate columns using SQL
I have a CTE that produces this sample result:



ID
Type
Date
InitialVal
EndVal




100
Status
2023-04-18
Pending Review
Need Signature


100
Status
2023-10-03
Need Signature
In Progress


100
Status
2024-01-02
In Progress
Testing


100
Status
2024-05-04
Testing
Completed


101
State
2023-08-29
Inactive
Active


101
State
2023-10-14
Active
Inactive



I need to determine the time that this item was in a particular Status (or State), or basically doing a DATEDIFF between rows where the EndVal matches the InitialVal for the same ID.
I've tried using LAG and LEAD, but I am not getting the expected results. LAG will exclude the time spent in the first status, and LEAD was producing negative numbers and excluding the time spent until the last change.

This fiddle might help us collaborate on a solution https://dbfiddle.uk/OQy1Ks6_

Show us your attempts; LEAD/LAG seems to be exactly what you want.

I don't think you need to match up the EndVale of the previous record with the Initialval of the current record because they all seem to follow the lag pattern.

SELECT *,
   LAG(EndVal) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY [Date])  as PrevEndVal,
   LAG([Date]) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY [Date])  as PrevDate,
   DATEDIFF(Day, LAG([Date]) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY [Date]), [date]) as DayDiff
FROM Example

fiddle



ID
Type
Date
InitialVal
EndVal
PrevEndVal
PrevDate
DayDiff




100
Status
2023-04-18
Pending Review
Need Signature
null
null
null


100
Status
2023-10-03
Need Signature
In Progress
Need Signature
2023-04-18
168


100
Status
2024-01-02
In Progress
Testing
In Progress
2023-10-03
91


100
Status
2024-05-04
Testing
Completed
Testing
2024-01-02
123


101
State
2023-08-29
Inactive
Active
null
null
null


101
State
2023-10-14
Active
Inactive
Active
2023-08-29
46




This is incredibly close. I was only doing LAG on the Date, and that was tripping me up. One aspect I neglected to mention is that the same ID can have multiple Types (State and Status). The only failure point on this is when an ID has both, it puts an erroneous PrevEndVal for when it switches Types. I'm thinking we can actually filter these out in the reporting tool we use, but if there is a way to account for that beforehand, I'd welcome it.

@Nathan Armaly Please provide an example

@Nathan Armaly Maybe we can fix that by using "Partition By ID,Type" https://dbfiddle.uk/GRxqYKkH
